# SSRS axis categories not in sort order

Tags: sorting, reporting-services

I have four categories on my line graph to designate quarters in an academic year - Summer, Fall, Winter, Spring - in that order.  The sort field used on the category field gives a numbered string value to each quarter, from 1 to 4.  Instead of coming out in the desired order, it comes out as Summer Winter Fall Spring instead.  Winter is 3 and Fall is 2, so I can't figure out what is wrong.  I've looked at the data and verified the sort field is correctly matched.  I don't know what else to check.  This is SSRS Report Builder 3.0.  Thank you!!

Comment: Is this programming related? I cant see any code

Comment: No, not programming related, just can't make the categories come out in the right order for my report.  Can't figure out why because the numbers are in the order they should be, and the categories are correctly matched with the numbers but they are out of order when the graph is rendered.

Comment: Well stackoverflow is a website for *programming* related questions. I guess you need to ask Microsoft support.

Comment: LJ, there are many SSRS questions asked and answered daily here.  @TiaG Try adding a column to your dataset query that uses a case statement to set numbers 1-4 based on quarter.  If you need help doing this, let me know.

Comment: strings will not sort correctly I have not yet found out why but you have to assign the values as integers not as strings. Once you do that you should get the desired results.

Comment: Thank you Sonny and SFrejofsky!  I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the group properties? Look at them at the bottom of the report, there is a property called Sorting, try to use it with the quarter number.